# How to destroy a user's account after first login - php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a voting system, where user register and vote, so the unique part of it is one user one vote, am looking for a way to destroy a user account after the first login. so that the user wont be able to login and vote again.
Am using php + mysql

Example of login Details

Username and password

Comment: This site isn't a Q-A for scripts.

Comment: Just set a flag in the database table to 'delete' the user (or just hard delete the user). You should be able to find out how to do this from the MySQL docs - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/

Comment: Delete the user account in the DB after the user votes. or use a flag variable in the DB to check weather the user is already voted or not (this one is better).

Comment: don't remove the record . just add one flag into db poll (set with 0,1 default 0=not voted yet).change the value only and check and restrict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deleting the account you should keep record of the votes in the db. And, before making any entry in the db just check for the vote corresponding to current user and allow user to vote or not accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple :** Use a vote Flag in DB. Set VoteFlag=true when he is voted. This will help you in prepare poll reports etc.

Or

**Advanced :** you can use little more complicated method, just log the votes in a table, with foreign key user, use join queries to find unvoted / voted users

This idea is based on a college mini project done by me.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment the question :)